# To obtain the maximum value of $abc+abd+acd+bcd$ under the conditions $a+b+c+d=4$, $a, b, c, d >0$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $a,b,c$ and $d$ be positive integer numbers such that  $a+b+c+d=4$.

*My question:*

what is the maximum value of the relation given in $(1)$?

> $$abc+abd+acd+bcd  \tag{1}$$

*My try:*

I'm pretty sure that the maximum value would be obtained by taking $a=b=c=d=1$, but I wouldn't know how to prove it.

Comment: $a,b,c,d$ aren't necessarily integers

Comment: Using Lagrange you'll nearly immediately find $a=b=c=d=1$.

Comment: You right. I made a mistake in typing. Please edit your question and delete the word "integer". Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe how exactly ?

Comment: Foa a start: Let $$f(a,b,c,d,\lambda)=abc+abd+acd+bcd-\lambda(a+b+c+d-4).$$ Subtract $f_a$ from $f_b$ and factorize.

Comment: This is a special case of [Maclaurin's inequaility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin's_inequality). According to wiki, this can be proved using [Newton's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_inequalities).